# How to open a file and view on remote windows machine

Tags: java, windows, jakarta-ee, command-line, remote-access

I want to open a file on remote windows machine from my local windows machine. The file should be visible on remote machine only.

My problem is, I should open a bat file on remote pc which creates access to do something like opening browser etc.

I did using **PSExec** to run the bat file remotely. Everything looked good, but when i try to open the browser on remote pc, it does not open browser but shows browser processes in task manager.

When I go and open that bat file manually on remote machine everything works fine. Browser opens and my work is done.

But I want to do that from my local machine especially from the command line. So that I can use this commands in Java.

Please help. If question is not clear please ask for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the -i option with psexec or specifying a session ie. -i 1

From the psexec manual.

'-i Run the program so that it interacts with the desktop of the specified session on the remote system. If no session is specified the process runs in the console session.'

example:

C:\SysinternalsSuite\psexec.exe \remotecomputer -u DOMAIN\administrator -p adminpass -i 1 "\remotecomputer\c$\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://tinyurl.com/6fbgntx

Comment: Thanks you very much. I missed a small(-i) thing. Now everything works fine.

Comment: if you think this question has been answered, mark it as having a correct solution or people will thing there is still a question outstanding.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use WMI - It management instrumentation. It allows running process on remote machine (obviously if you have enough permissions). 
You can either access WMI from Java using one of popular interoparability libraries (JaWin, JInterop, JIntegra) or write JScript or VBScript and execute it from java.

JaWin and Jinterop are open-source. JIntegra is not. 
JaWin requires windows OS on client machine. JIntegra and JInterop can be executed from other OS.

I used all 2 suggested methods and all 3 libraries. Probably now I prefer JInterop.